# 301 redirect of pages not working opencart

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, opencart

direct some pages to the homepage of opencart.

For examle:
`https://mywebsitenamehere.com/index.php?route=product/manufacturer`

301 redirect to:
`https://mywebsitenamehere.com/`

I would usually add something like this:

```
Redirect 301 /index.php?route=product/manufacturer https://mywebsitenamehere.com/
```

Snippet of my .htaccess:

```
# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/storage/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)

RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Checking if answer below worked for you. If yes then make sure to mark the answer as accepted or else let us know if there is still a problem

Comment: It didn't work but there was another way .. I will write it here when I get a sec!

Comment: UPDATE: 

in (for example) 
manufacturer.php

add the following to the very top:
<?php // to redirect page
header( 'Location: https://mywebsitenamehere.com/' ) ;
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

in (for example)

```
manufacturer.php
```

add the following to the very top:

```
<?php // to redirect page
header( 'Location: https://mywebsitenamehere.com/' ) ;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/storage/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=product/manufacturer [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php https://mywebsitenamehere.com [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: There are actually multiple URLs I want to redirect (but all to the homepage). I thought if we got one working I could go ahead and do the others.

The homepage is:https://mywebsitenamehere.com/

but I have recently noticed the url sometimes appears as: https://mywebsitenamehere.com/index.php?route=common/home

Two example pages I want to 301 redirect to the homepage are https://mywebsitenamehere.com/index.php?route=product/manufacturer
OR https://mywebsitenamehere.com/index.php?route=account/voucher

Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: @ReggieWills, ok could you please try following `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=(product|account)/(manufacturer|voucher) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php https://mywebsitenamehere.com [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^ index.php?route=%1/%2 [L]` I am posting it here for time being once you confirm then I will post them in my answer, also all rules have new lines in between them but stack's comment don't recognize it so edit it accordingly, please check these and get back to me, quick response will be appreciated cheers :)

Comment: @ReggieWills, strange, are you hitting mywebsitenamehere.com/index.php?route=product/manufacturer url in your browser?

Comment: I was hitting that link yep, wasn't letting me add a comment sorry!